# Django: Migrating from MEDIA_URL to STATIC_URL

Tags: django

Since Django 1.3 the concept of STATIC_URL has been introduced to separate use media files from css and js files.

I have set my `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/project/static/'` and 
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

In my base.html, i have changed the path like this:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in `url.py` I have added the following two lines:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My view renders the template with RequestCOntext:

```
return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables)
```

But in the development I still get 404 when running runserver.

```
[18/Aug/2012 17:12:04] "GET /static/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.py

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media')
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

That should work :)

Comment: Thanks Efrin. The key was that I had to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to the physical static files, while leaving the actual path to static files empty, as this will be collected by manage.py later on. COnfusing... :)

Comment: could you point where `static` directory should be placed? should it be ing something like `/<project_name>/<project_name>/` or somwhere else?

Comment: is `collectstatic` needed?

Comment: are some `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in settings needed for local development?

Comment: all right. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/