# Static file management in Django1.4

Tags: django, static-files, django-staticfiles, django-1.4

I've been confused with static files in Django for days. I found one solution that worked fine. But it collapsed when I set DEBUG=False. So I build up a new project and do some tests to get a clearer look.
First I create a project with the default settings. Then I changed some lines of the setting file into:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '%s/site_media' % PROJECT_DIR
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images'),
)
```

After that, I put 'hi.jpg' at 'project_dir/images/hi.jpg'. I call runserver and visit 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/hi.jpg'. It doesn't work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it works: when `DEBUG=True` then Django serves the static files itself. When `DEBUG=False` then Django won't do that anymore and you'll need to configure your web server to do it (such as Apache).

Django has a mechanism for that in `django.contrib.staticfiles` (see [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and [The staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)). It basically means that you need to run the `collectstatic`management command which will search for all static files in `/static/` directories in your Django project and it will put them in one directory (`STATIC_ROOT`). When that has been done, your web server can serve the static files from that directory.

If one or more static files can't be found after running `collectstatic` then that means you have configured something incorrectly.

Comment: I got my mistake:I should visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/hi.jpg without prefix 'image' since STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images'),) not (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, ''),)

Comment: Is it possible if I set DEBUG=False and do local development? Since I use celery which would throw a warning if DEBUG=True

Comment: @user1606453: Well, you can but then your local web server also needs to be configured to serve the static files.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media')
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

:)

[Django: Migrating from MEDIA_URL to STATIC_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020186/django-migrating-from-media-url-to-static-url/12020262#comment16039517_12020262)